# Code signing several projects in one solution in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, code-signing, solution, signtool

I am new to .Net and I received a task where I am supposed to sign existing WPF .net solution with a certificate. The thing is, that the solution consists of several projects from which some are installers, one is update service, there are several libraries and one is the actual application. We are distributing an installer for people to use.

So my question is: what do I need to sign? So far we were signing just the compiled installer outside visual studio, but I am not sure whether it is enough. Should I sign all the projects separately? And is there some automated function for this or do I have to sign it manually everytime by signtool? 
Also there are lots of texts about clickonce signing, strong names, signing assemblies, signing manifests, signing files.... I am a little bit lost in all of this, so can someone please clarify what are the main differences and usages for these options?
Thank you a lot :)

Comment: I would just sign the stuff that you compile.  I also would ask for clarification on what exactly needs to be signed.  How you create a signed assembly is pretty self explanatory since your using Visual Studio.

Comment: Good question, I could use a good explanation about the ins and outs of signing.

Comment: just try installshield.